# Raspberry Pi Rails Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, raspberry-pi

I am looking for an image which includes a Ruby on Rails installation for the Raspberry Pi. 
Is there anything out there ?

Answer (score 2):

Will it works for you ? http://elinux.org/RPi_Ruby_on_Rails and also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/setting-up-a-ruby-on-rails-server

Comment: Yes I tried this already but it doesn't worked until now. I am looking for a predefined image.

Comment: Here is a Raspberry image with rails installed:

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27198452/rasp/wheezy_rails.tar.bz2
Instruction:
extract: `tar -xjf wheezy_rails.tar.bz2`
write to sd (X is your sd device): `sudo dd bs=4M if=wheezy_rails.img of=/dev/sdX`

Comment: @der_wolle You can always post your answer as well..thx for sharing